# numbers to roman numeral using switch case

Tags: java

so I have a homework where I have to make a program to change numbers to roman numeral. I want to use switch cases but I don't want to write out every single number from 1-3999. I was told that we can do it by changing the cases to different numbers places separately but I do not understand how that works this is what i have for the ones place and tens place but how would I put them together?

```
public class Number {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 3999: ");
    int number= scan.nextInt();
    String numberString;

    switch (number%10) 
    {
        case 1:  numberString = "I";
                 break;
        case 2:  numberString = "II";
                 break;
        case 3:  numberString = "III";
                 break;
        case 4:  numberString = "IV";
                 break;
        case 5:  numberString = "V";
                 break;
        case 6:  numberString = "VI";
                 break;
        case 7:  numberString = "VII";
                 break;
        case 8:  numberString = "VIII";
                 break;
        case 9:  numberString = "IX";
                 break;
        default: numberString = "Invalid nummber";
                 break;
    }

    switch ((number%100)/10) 
    {
        case 1:  numberString = "X";
                 break;
        case 2:  numberString = "XX";
                 break;
        case 3:  numberString = "XXX";
                 break;
        case 4:  numberString = "XL";
                 break;
        case 5:  numberString = "L";
                 break;
        case 6:  numberString = "LX";
                 break;
        case 7:  numberString = "LXX";
                 break;
        case 8:  numberString = "LXXX";
                 break;
        case 9:  numberString = "XC";
                 break;
        default: numberString = "Invalid nummber";
                 break;
    }
    System.out.println(numberString);
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to deal with the zero case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to your second switch case, you rewrite the variable numberString. For example, when I give it the number 18 to convert, the first switch case will assign numberString to the value "VIII". But then I move on to the second switch case and it is overwritten with the value "X", which is then printed. In your second switch case, you should be using

```
    case 1: numberString += "X";
            break;
```

In addition, you should switch the order in which you perform your switch statements. Use your switch ((number%100)/10) first and the other one second. This will put the number of X's in the front of each number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you could swap the order of your `switch`s and use `String` concatenation. Something like,

```
String numberString = "";
switch ((number%100)/10) 
{
    case 1:  numberString += "X";
             break;
    case 2:  numberString += "XX";
             break;
    case 3:  numberString += "XXX";
             break;
    case 4:  numberString += "XL";
             break;
    case 5:  numberString += "L";
             break;
    case 6:  numberString += "LX";
             break;
    case 7:  numberString += "LXX";
             break;
    case 8:  numberString += "LXXX";
             break;
    case 9:  numberString += "XC";
             break;
    default: numberString = "Invalid nummber";
             break;
}

switch (number%10) 
{
    case 1:  numberString += "I";
             break;
    case 2:  numberString += "II";
             break;
    case 3:  numberString += "III";
             break;
    case 4:  numberString += "IV";
             break;
    case 5:  numberString += "V";
             break;
    case 6:  numberString += "VI";
             break;
    case 7:  numberString += "VII";
             break;
    case 8:  numberString += "VIII";
             break;
    case 9:  numberString += "IX";
             break;
    default: numberString = "Invalid nummber";
             break;
}

System.out.println(numberString);
```

Comment: oh thank I knew that I was missing something small thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution without using switch? It works perfectly.

```
public class Solution {
    public String intToRoman(int num) {
        String result = "";

        int M = num / 1000;
        num = num % 1000;
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) result += "M";

        int CM = num / 900;
        num = num % 900;
        for(int i=0; i<CM; i++) result += "CM";

        int D = num / 500;
        num = num % 500;
        for(int i=0; i<D; i++) result += "D";

        int CD = num / 400;
        num = num % 400;
        for(int i=0; i<CD; i++) result += "CD";

        int C = num / 100;
        for(int i=0; i<C; i++) result += "C";
        num = num % 100;

        int XC = num / 90;
        num = num % 90;
        for(int i=0; i<XC; i++) result += "XC";

        int L = num / 50;
        num = num % 50;
        for(int i=0; i<L; i++) result += "L";

        int XL = num / 40;
        num = num % 40;
        for(int i=0; i<XL; i++) result += "XL";

        int X = num / 10;
        for(int i=0; i<X; i++) result += "X";
        num = num % 10;

        int IX = num / 9;
        num = num % 9;
        for(int i=0; i<IX; i++) result += "IX";

        int V = num / 5;
        num = num % 5;
        for(int i=0; i<V; i++) result += "V";

        int IV = num / 4;
        num = num % 4;
        for(int i=0; i<IV; i++) result += "IV";

        int I = num;
        for(int i=0; i<I; i++) result += "I";

        return result;
    }
}
```